# Display list of information in separate divs using thymeleaf and spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Apologies in advance if the question may be too generalized or simple, but it is my first application using Spring.

What I am trying to do is as follows :
I have a dashboard with 3 columns and 5 rows each.
Every div has information like : Name and Score.

My application has the following models:

```
public class Client{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID")
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String lastName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonManagedReference  
  private List<SurveyData> survey= new ArrayList<SurveyData>();

  private char gender;

}

public class SurveyData {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "SURVEY_ID")
  private Long Id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonBackReference
  @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
  public Client client;

  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonManagedReference
  @JoinColumn(name = "surveyresult_id")
  private SurveyResults surveyResults;
}


 public class SurveyResults{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "SURVEYRESULT_ID")
   private Long Id;
   private Double score;
}
```

So what I want to display on the columns is clients name,last name and score that's on SurveyResults.

Something like this for example :

*Order by Score, descending.Select top 5 with highest score and display*

Now I know that the query would go on the Repository.
But the results that this would return, in a list or whatever the best way would be .. how to display them on the html file, thymeleaf?

I'm so sorry again if I'm being confusing or the question is simple, I just need a bit of guidance on what best practices are  and how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

```
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-2">
         <h3>#1</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
         <img>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
          <h4 style="color: black;">
          <b>NAME</b>
          </h4>
          <p style="font-size: 11px;">
           Score: <b>SCORE from db</b>
           </p>
          </div>
           </div>
           <br />
           <div class="row ">
           <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>#2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img></div>
             <div class="col-sm-7">
            <h4 style="color: black;">
            <b>NAME </b>
             </h4>
              <p style="font-size: 11px;">
              Score: <b>SCORE from db</b>
              </p>
              </div>
              </div>
              ....repeated for several rows
```

Comment: Where from are you expecting the data of client and surveyresult? From a different api call? Please also post the Controller code where you are rendering the page.

Comment: Thank you for answering, kinda what I meant to ask.
How to pass a List of results to the controller that renders the page, so that I can access it in thymeleaf.
I know model.addAttribute(), but I didn't want ot pass them one by one

Comment: No you dont have to pass them one by one. You can pass any Object, any list, any primitive data types from your controller method and then use those objects in the thymleaf page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Thymeleaf iterator as shown below:

```
<div class="row" th:each="c : ${clients}">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 th:text=" |${c.name}, ${c.lastName}| "></h2>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Score</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each= " s : ${c.surveyResults}">
                    <td th:text=" ${s.score}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

So with the above code, you will have one section for each client and under it a table of scores. Make sure you set the clients information in the model attribute `clients`

Comment: Thank you.But this way I would post clients information one after another ?
Cuz what I need to do is have a controller that returns a list of top 5 clients, and then my question was how to pass that list on thymeleaf ?
i.e  extend SurveyResults repository, and make an orderBy(score) that returns a list of SurveyResults.
And then that access name,last name and score. 
How do I pass the that on thymeleaf

Comment: Please clarify: you have a `List<SurveyData>` with top 5 `SurveyResults`? Am I right?  And you want to display the client information in the Survey data along with its score? Am I right? You know how to get the `List<SurveyData>` with top 5 `SurveyResults` but dont know how to show it on UI. Am I right?